# flexbox margin cause overflow

Tags: html, css, grid, flexbox

i have a little problem of overflowing with flexbox :

**html**

```
<div class="first">
            <div class="child"></div>
            <div class="child"></div>
            <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 50px;
}
.first {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
}

.child {
    background: red;
    border: 1px blue solid;
    height: 10px;
    flex: 0 0 33.3%;

    margin-right: 10px;
}

.first :last-child {
    flex: 0 0 33.4%;
}
```

the problem is that the last child is overflowing, why?? i used box-sizing to border-box?

Comment: `box-sizing` has no effect on margins! What is it you are trying to do?

Comment: well, how to add margin between children without causing the overflow

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> How to add margin between children without causing the overflow

I think this is what you are trying to do:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 50px;
}

.first {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  border:1px solid green;
}

.child {
  background: red;
  border: 1px blue solid;
  height: 10px;
  flex: 1; /* equal widths */
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.first :last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="first">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Alternatively, you can use `calc` to set the child widths and `justify-content:space-between` on the flex-container

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  margin: 50px;
}
.first {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  border: 1px solid green;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.child {
  background: red;
  border: 1px blue solid;
  height: 10px;
  width: calc((100% - 20px)/3);
  /* or */
  flex: 0 0 calc((100% - 20px)/3);
}
```

```html
<div class="first">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```